# Update AWS WAF IP set without any tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-application-firewall, amazon-waf

I am trying to automate the process of updating WAF IP sets.

Is there a way to update the WAF ip-set without making use of a token such as `--change-token` or `--lock-token`?